# Почему вынесение переменной за pjax влияет на работу DatePicker?

Tags: php, yii2, pjax, kartik

Есть простой код:

```
Pjax::begin(['id' => "test-grid-pjax", 'enablePushState' => false, 'enableReplaceState' => false]);

echo GridView::widget([
    'id' => "test-grid",
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $columns,
]);

Pjax::end();
```

И есть определение колонок. Они вынесены в переменную:

```
$columns = [
    'id',
    [
        'attribute' => 'start_guarantee_period',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->start_guarantee_period;
        },
        'filter' => kartik\date\DatePicker::widget(['value' => $searchModel->start_guarantee_period, 'name' => 'ItemSearch[start_guarantee_period]', 'pluginOptions' => [
                'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                'todayHighlight' => true
            ],
        ]),
    ],
];
```

`DatePicker` используется от картика, то есть [этот](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker)
У `DatePicker` есть иконки выбора даты и сброса.

- Если инициализацию переменной `$columns` поместить внутрь *Pjax*, т.е. **ПОСЛЕ** тега `Pjax::begin`, то можно кликнуть иконку даты, выбрать дату, данные отфильтруются. Потом ещё раз нажать, выбрать дату, отфильтруются и т.д.
- Если инициализацию переменной `$columns` поместить за *Pjax*, т.е. **ДО** тега `Pjax::begin`, то можно выбрать дату только первый раз. После перезагрузки таблицы клик по иконкам не вызывают никаких событий. Просто мертвы.

Да, JS отваливается после перезагрузки контента. Да, можно это починить либо поместив `$columns` внутрь тега `Pjax` или после перезагрузки таблицы выполнить js код `$('#w0-kvdate').kvDatepicker(window.kvDatepicker_33d8ead7);` для перезапуска пикера.

---

**Основной вопрос:** почему такая магия происходит? Почему позиция переменной в **конкретном выше** коде *PHP* на сервере каким-то образом влияет на поведение *JS*? Я понимаю, если бы происходил `echo` переменной, а `pjax` буферизировал бы этот вывод и выводил после навешивания слушателей в *JS*. Но здесь всего лишь меняется позиция определения переменной. Как влияет? Почему перестаёт работать?

Comment: Теги после отработки Pjax меняется? Точнее ID.

Comment: @mepihindeveloper id пикера? нет. Поэтому после работы фильтра можно спокойно в консоли написать `$('#w0-kvdate').kvDatepicker(window.kvDatepicker_33d8ead7);` и пикер заново будет работать. Если ещё раз выбрать дату и опять написать `$('#w0-kvdate').kvDatepicker(window.kvDatepicker_33d8ead7);`, то опять пикер будет работать и т.д.  Т.е. id всегда одинаковые

Comment: А как в итоге всё выглядит в браузере? Возможно происходит перезапись или изменение переменной $column где-то позже? По ощущениям выглядит как проблема контекста ...

Comment: @DanielProtopopov нет. изменение переменной нигде не происходит. Это чистый пример на чистой странице специально сделал)) если только внутри виджетов как-то что-то магическое происходит. внутри того же pjax. но я посмотрев в исходники не увидел ничего такого. проблема определённо из-за перезаписи и потери слушателя. но не ясно как это вообще так влияет. одно с другим же никак не связано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто. Когда Вы выносите `Columns` за `pjax`, а следовательно и подключаемый в нем `DatePicker`, - то все подгружаемые для его работы `js-скрипты` подключатся перед `</body>`.

```html
<html>
<head>
..тут подключаются .css
</head>
<body>

<script src=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

И все `css-селекторы` в них прописаны на конкретные классы.

```js
var initDPRemove = function () {
}, initDPAddon = function () {
};
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.kvDatepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
    initDPRemove = function (id, range) {
        var $id = $('#' + id), $el = $id.parent(), $input;
        $el.find('.kv-date-remove').on('click.kvdatepicker', function () {
            if (range) {
                $el.find('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
                    $(this).kvDatepicker('clearDates').trigger('change');
                });
            } else {
                $el.kvDatepicker('clearDates');
                $input = $el.is('input') ? $el : $el.find('input[type="text"]');
                $input.trigger('change');
            }
        });
    };
    initDPAddon = function (id) {
        var $id = $('#' + id), $el = $id.parent(),
            pickers = '.input-group-addon:not(.kv-date-picker):not(.kv-date-remove)' +
                ',.input-group-text:not(.kv-date-picker):not(.kv-date-remove)';
        $el.find(pickers).each(function () {
            var $addon = $(this);
            $addon.on('click.kvdatepicker', function () {
                $el.kvDatepicker('hide');
            });
        });
        $el.find('.input-group-addon.kv-date-picker').on('click.kvdatepicker', function () {
            $id.focus();
        });
    };
})(window.jQuery);
```

Как Вы сами писали - после того как сработает `pjax` все `bind` на классы отвалятся т.к они по сути пропадут из `DOM`, а потом снова туда добавятся, но уже без `bind`. А вот если Вы вставите `Columns` после инициализации `Pjax` то все необходимые для его работы `js-скрипты` будут подключаться заново после каждой подгрузки содержимого `pjax` т.к `<script scr="></script>` будет прописан внутри `pjax`-контейнера, а соответственно инициализация `datepicker` будет вызвана снова и на все описанные в `js`-скрипте классы снова будет навешан `bind`.

Так что либо Вы все же перенесите `$columns` внутрь `pjax` - либо перепишите `kartik`-овский `js` на `bind` на `body` :)

```js
$('body').on('click', '...', function(){
});
```

Comment: Я думал, что при добавлении виджета в массив (не важно какой), в ключ  например  `'filter' => kartik\date\DatePicker::widget` то вся инициализация будет ленивой, т.е. произойдёт всё во время отрисовки уже самого грида. А по сути, дело в том, что как только интерпретатор дойдёт до строки `kartik\date\DatePicker::widget` он тут же его инициализирует и выполнит его внутренний  метод regsisterAssets. Ещё до того, как дойдёт до разбора строк с Pjax. Правильно понимаю?

Comment: Абсолютно верно.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо))